# Is it possible to view ip addresses of chrome history rather than urls?

Tags: google-chrome, ip, history

Is it possible to view chrome history as ip addresses rather than urls?
The reason is that in my history I have a site that is hosted on multiple servers and I want to pick out a particular one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you really need to do, may be a sniffer is more suitable. I would use wireshark for example.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible you can track your website with full details. You need to add your hosted website url in yahoo or google google webmaster tools.
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en
That will give you wonderful tracking result.